# gpg: "keyserver receive failed" for the key F987672F while installing wine package on ubuntu

Tags: apt, wine, docker

I am trying to install Wine package on ubuntu via a Dockerfile. The The install steps are as follows;

```
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386 \
    && apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 76F1A20FF987672F \
    && apt-get update \
        && apt-add-repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/' \
        && wget https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key \
        && apt-key add Release.key \
        && apt update \
        && apt install -y --no-install-recommends winehq-staging
```

Error:

```
gpg: requesting key F987672F from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv F987672F`

Comment: The issue was resolved by replacing the unsigned Release.key with winehq.key from the wine download server.